# Fastest way to compile small Java files

Tags: java, javac

I'm looking to programmatically compile (not through IDE) a few small classes such as:

```java
public class Sum {
  public int sum(int[] nums) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      total += nums[i];
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

Running `javac Sum.java` takes `429ms` on macOS (2.3 GHz Intel Core i5) but in a Kubernetes container (t3.xlarge) with 3VCPU, and 6G of RAM, it takes `640ms`. What causes this difference?

I tried different java versions and tried using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` but with few files, it takes up to 2 seconds to compile 3 small files like these.

What's the best configuration of hardware/software to make a compilation of these small files fastest?

Comment: First you ask about *Fastest way to compile small Java files*; then you touch the Kubernetes/Containers; then you incorporate `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`; and finally you're questioning what is the *best configuration of hardware/software to make compilation fastest*. - It seems like you're not really understanding what you are doing and/or what you want to achieve specifically. I would suggest you to specify - what exactly you have as a question? hardware/software combinations, builds, kernel I/O or CPU chipset should not really be of any interest when compiling Java code or using Kubernetes.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm looking for anything to make compilation as fast as possible and these are some of the things I already tried to achieve that goal.

Comment: Are you compiling the files one by one or as a single batch call to the compiler? ... and anyway...what's the point of this really?

Comment: Why compilation time worries you at all? it shouldn't be *too slow* to make you struggle because of that.. any Pentium 2 CPU with 512 RAM (or even less) should compile your files smoothly.. ***IFF*** you are concerned with compilation, per se.. because, *compiling* the code, and incorporating any containers, or VMs or etc. are two completely disparate tasks, that have nothing in common. Fastest way to compile a file, which produces `.class` bytecode files, is to just use bare `javac`.

Comment: I don't know the circumstance but premature optimization can waste a lot of time and even cause problems. This was a hard lesion for me to learn back in the day. If whatever you are doing is not having problems with complication speed yet I would recommend ignoring this and coming back to it if it actually ends up needing optimization.

Comment: *speeding up compilation* has never been a premature optimization, or optimization at all. Let the native OS calls do what they do. I also don't really understand how one should *make compilation faster*.

Comment: `time` is not a recognized tool for me. What do you mean *do you find it normal*? Yes, I find it normal, as long as I'm not interested how the `javac.exe` calls my OS API and translates Java into bytecode. At least, that is not the depth, mere person running `javac OneClass.java`, and then trying that into `Kubernetes`, should be worried about.. my point is not that *it can't be done in a less time*. Your last comment is a derogatory, and what you think is a preposterous, might not be the same for others. Please be more respectful.. I might think otherwise, but I don't express that like this.

Comment: Besides, hardware and the software which OP uses as a platform (in this case OS, and C++ native code used in `javac`), are *constant factors*. Even if something consumes a bit longer time, and that can be tweaked, it still depends on **a lot of things** - why it does so. Build of Java, VM version, OS, hardware, CPU architecture, RAM, and etc. So, yes, I think that *compilation time* optimization is not really a case when OP asks (citation) "I'm looking for compiling few small classes".. trying that in kubernetes, VM or etc.

Comment: `time` is a tool on OSes except windows which simply times what you type after it. Finding it 'normal' that it takes ~1000msec to parse 12 characters and write 180 bytes is utterly bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number I just got empirically is 5ms/file...

If you have a lot of Java files to compile, then maybe you care about this.  But if that's the case, then the timing numbers you're talking about are not realistic.  I wrote this program to compile your test program 1000 times (I created 1000 java files defining classes Sum0 through Sum999.

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int N = 1000;
        String[] files = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
            files[i] = String.format("stage/Sum%d.java", i);
        }
        int result = compiler.run(null, null, null, files);
        System.out.println("Compile result code = " + result);
    }
}
```

I ran it, and here are the timing figures for that run:

```
> ls stage/*.class | wc -l
ls: stage/*.class: No such file or directory
       0

> time java T
Compile result code = 0

real    0m2.511s
user    0m4.737s
sys 0m0.549s

> ls stage/*.class | wc -l
    1000
```

So the total runtime was 4.737 seconds / 1000 = .005 seconds = 5 ms /file.  All I can think of is that you're compiling files one at a time, in which case all the time is some kind of startup/teardown cost, and who cares about that.

The bottom line is that you can probably compile however many Java files you want in just a few seconds, so stop worrying about this.

This was run on a couple of generations back MacBook Pro.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and providing code. I'll try this myself to understand it better. But in this case, is the compilation fast because it's compiling the same contents? Or because startup/teardown only happens once?

Comment: I hope it's the latter, but I admit that there's a chance the former has something to do with it.  I obviously wasn't going to go out and write 1000 unique programs to try this.  Even if the answer is somewhere in between, it shows that the time to compile one file isn't likely to be worth anything in projecting how long it will take to compile 1000 files.

Comment: I would still suggest @petabyte to not worry about this at all. With all respect, but when you try to improve the speed in a completely unrelated fields (like Kubernetes), that means, that you're not really rewriting the compiler in C/C++.. but just learning curiously (which is great).. so, from the learning perspective, there are still a lot of very interesting things you'll get tired with, in Java. (in a good sense) :) Good luck.

Comment: Nothing wrong with curiosity in these areas.  But if you're looking to get work done, hold to the famous Knuth adage..."Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  In other words, worry about a speed problem when you have a speed problem.

Comment: @Steve I have written "which is great" - about curiosity.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri - Ah Yes!  I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 2):

Wahaaaaaay back in the distant, distant past, we had 'incremental compilers'. These would run *continuously*. You start them up once at the start of the day or whatnot and then just leave em running forever. They would then either wait for any keyboard input (an enter press), or set up some file watches (hooks that trigger when any file is modified in a given directory) and recompile every time that was needed. This saves VM warmup and VM boot loading.

I think they mostly died out as the build tools (particularly maven and gradle) became popular. The model doesn't mesh well with build systems; the build system *itself* should be the incremental unit (should run once and stay loaded), and must therefore also internalize the compiler in order to avoid having to init and warmup a VM every time it needs to compile.

Given that you want to compile one simple single small file, the VM init and compiler warmup is most likely 99% of that 640ms. An incremental compiler would be precisely what you need.

Incremental compilers still exist, but the only modern one I know of, is eclipse: If you save a file in eclipse, eclipse will almost instantaneously compile it using its own built in compiler. That's.. clearly not what you're looking for.

You can search the web if something incremental still exists and is decently maintained. You should also be able to handroll this, perhaps: Have a java app that will do something like: Listen for any full lines on system input (e.g. with Scanner and `.useDelimiter("\r?\n"); .next()`, treats those lines as files or dirs, will scan those for any new or changed files, invoke `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` on all changed things, and then update a hashmap mapping files to timestamps, and then go back to sleep waiting for more System.in traffic, using that map to decide on caches. Or forget the map and go old style: Find the class file, compare its timestamp to the source file's timestamp, and if the class file's stamp is newer, there is no need to recompile it. This doesn't quite map perfectly onto how java works (1 source file can produce multiple class files and it is not possible to determine from a class file name which source file produced it, though you probably can if you add enough debug info and open it up, but class files are quite a complex format so doing that is non-trivial) - so I'd do the hashmap, even if the compilers of yore went with the 'compare class file last-modified with source file' option.

Alternatively it could open up a TCP/IP port.

Note that eclipse also comes in 'language server' form which is exactly how VSCode works: When you edit java code in VSCode, VS starts a headless eclipse and uses it to do, well, everything 'intelligent' about java: Refactor scripts, live compilation, errors, warnings and general linting services, nav services (such as 'open type', 'find callers'), the debugger, and more. Compiling is part of the bevy of services that eclipse-as-a-language-server offers, and ecj is 4 to 10 times faster than javac to boot (speed of actual compilation after VM init and warmup is probably a fraction of a percent of that 640ms, so therefore not relevant, but I don't know exactly how fast you need this to be).

Comment: My answer seems to demonstrate your theory of "compiler warmup" which I suspected the moment I saw this question.

Comment: I am noticing different interpretations of this question. I interpreted it as: I will, over the span of many hours, have a need to compile a handful of tiny files every so often, and as I'm paying by the CPU cycle or otherwise interested, having to 'pay up' 640ms worth of time every time seems an _incredibly_ steep time for what seems so simple. Whereas some others seem to have interpreted it as: "Hey, it takes 640ms to compile one file, soo.. if I compile 100 of these, do I have to wait 5 minutes, oh dear!" - which fortunately isn't true.